# Photo From Device to FTP

Tags: ftp, device, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm making an application in which a device will send a photo to my ftp server and I shall display that photo in a webpage. Now, I have configured the Windows FTP Server(2008 R2) and Everything Works fine. i.e. when i copy and paste files into ftp via my windows explorer it shows up. But however I'm unable to receive files from the remote device. I called up the other team, they say that the device is sending photo and showing success message. Any idea how to cure this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the device was sending data via GSM connection, which had a slow speed. I had to set higher timeouts in FTP to made it work.